# When to consider catching Specific Exceptions Vs General Exception in Java

Tags: java, exception

> Catching specific exceptions like option 1 below is very common and also considered the save way to catch exceptions, Why the option 2 is rarely considered because of how ***verbose(not sure if that's the word to use!)*** it can become, that's what I understand so far.
>   My question is that are there any other instances when one should consider catching exceptions like option 2(General Exception) rather than Option 1 ?

### Opt1 -> Specific Exceptions:

```
try{
    TextIO.putf(s);
    FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("/content/doc/test.pdf", true);
}catch (FileNotFoundException notfEx){
       //Do something
}catch (NullPointerException nullEx){
       //Do something
}catch(IllegalArgumentException illEx){
       //Do something
}
```

### Opt2 -> General Exception:

```
try{
    TextIO.putf(s);
    FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("/content/doc/test.pdf", true);
   }catch (Exception ex){                
    if(ex.getClass() == java.io.FileNotFoundException.class) {
      //Do something
    }else if(ex.getClass() == java.lang.IllegalArgumentException.class){
      //Do something
    }else if(ex.getClass() == java.lang.NullPointerException.class){
      //Do something
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Faster?  Not the issue.  I'd worry more about clarity of code and intent.  Nano-optimizations like this do not matter.

Comment: Unrelated, but comparing `.getClass()` wouldn't include subclasses.  So (for example) the various subclasses of `IllegalArgumentException` would _not_ get dealt with by your `Do something` block.

Comment: I would be _surprised_ if the first option wasn't _very slightly_ faster on most implementations of the JDK (not saying it is...  Just I'd be surprised).  _But_ I also would really not worry about this unless you've discovered that this is a serious hot-point in your code, and if that's the case, either not using `Exception`s, or suppressing their stack trace creation would probably provide a significantly larger performance boost than choosing the right branching structure here.

Comment: @user2478398 which means that the first option will be faster?

Comment: @MartinR my question has been answered below. 
I was just thinking that the question is quite general.
If you want me to write the code sample for you in swift, let me know.

Comment: Asking a single question about two unrelated language is a road to getting your question voted to close as too broad. You need to ask specific and to the point questions.

Comment: Just for the record: this is probably not a great question, but I think there are good technical reasons to "answer", so this is not at all an "opinion only" question.

Comment: @GhostCat I agree with you, which is why I have voted to reopen.

Comment: Simply profile both implementations and compare the results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are simply asking the wrong question, a typical example of pre-mature optimisation.

The (potentially nil) difference in performance between your two options does **not** matter at all.

Keep in mind: you are talking about dealing with an exception that was just thrown.
Rest assured: creating that exception, and collecting its stack trace is *thousands of times* more expensive compared to some hypothetical gain because of using your options 1 or 2.

Thus: you can safely ignore performance here. You simply do what is easier to read, and easier to understand for human readers of your code. Which of course dictates to use version 1. And as the comments are pointing out: actually, your option 2 isn't equivalent to option 1 (as it ignores **sub classes** of exceptions). So, not only is that option 2 way harder to read and maintain, it is also very likely to result in unexpected (wrong) exception handling.

Finally: you are also victim of another common problem with newbie Java programmers. They assume that "what you do in source java" is the relevant factor for java performance at runtime. But that is not true. The real performance of java comes out of the JIT, and its efforts to compile java byte code into machine code. You have to make sure that the JIT can do a good job (and of course: to avoid stupid mistakes within your code). So again: your ideas do not contribute anything meaningful to "how to achieve performance".

Comment: And don't forget the fact that options 1 and 2 do not do the same thing. Option 1 will catch an exception type and all its subclasses, while option 2 will only handle a specific type only.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Duly noted!

Comment: If I was scared or unaware of the downvote my question will bring, then I won't say this:
I know I might lose part of my small rep on this question but pls I need an answer.

Comment: @Whales Well, using multiple tags is often a difficult thing, and can get you downvotes quickly. As the question stands by now (together with the answer), I think it is "okay" content (so I hope nobody comes in and deletes it).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel you mean catching a general exception which is option 2, only catches the specific subclass of Exception? while the option 1 will catch an exception type and all its subclasses ?

Comment: @Whales No, your usage of - for example - `if (ex.getClass() == java.lang.IllegalArgumentException.class)` will only handle exceptions that are exactly `IllegalArgumentException`, but not - for example - `NumberFormatException` (a subclass of `IllegalArgumentException`), while `catch (IllegalArgumentException e)` will handle both the specific type and its subclasses.

Comment: @GhostCat it's funny how ridiculous questions like mine are been attributed to newbies...I believe it's fine to be a newbie. Lol

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I am currently closing my eyes now...You should have posted an answer like this! Now I see more reasons why it's efficient catching Exception with the option one.
I have just opened the IllegalArgumentsException class now and I totally understand why you chose that way.
Believe me or not, not everyone knows...even the so-called expects, and posting a clear explanation like yours and GhostCat might really help others.

Comment: @Whales If you know in advance that your question will attract downvotes, then rather than get annoyed at everyone who makes comments you don't like, try to word your question in a way that will not attract downvotes in the first place. Also note that Stack Overflow is *not* a place for beginners to learn how to program - there are countless books and tutorials for that. Even beginners should make sure their questions are narrowly scoped, well written, come with MCVEs, aren't duplicates, have been pre-researched, etc. etc. None of that prevents you from asking a beginner-type question.

Comment: @JBentley I am wondering why you're so much offended! when an answer has already been posted.
By the way, let me know if the question is making more sense now as I have edited it else let me know if not then I can edit again.

Comment: @Whales What gave you the impression I am offended? I am not - I am simply offering you some advice on how to better approach questions in future.